# Create matrix with 2 arrays in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I want to find a command in numpy for a column vector times a row vector equals to a matrix

[1,1,1,1 ] ^T * [ 2,3 ] = [[2,3],[2,3],[2,3],[2,3]]

Answer (score 6):

First, let's define your 1-D numpy arrays:

```
In [5]: one = np.array([ 1,1,1,1 ]); two = np.array([ 2,3 ])
```

Now, lets multiply them:

```
In [6]: one[:, np.newaxis] * two[np.newaxis, :]
Out[6]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

This used numpy's `newaxis` to add the appropriate axes to get a 4x2 output matrix.

Comment: in my timings this showed to be faster than TimothyShields' approach

Comment: +1. This is the same approach as used by `np.outer(one, two)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is that both of your vectors are neither column nor row vectors - they're just vectors. If you look at `len(vec.shape)` it's `1`.

What you can do is use [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to turn your column vector into  shape `(m, 1)` and your row vector into shape `(1, n)`.

```
import numpy as np

colu = np.reshape(u, (u.shape[0], 1))
rowv = np.reshape(v, (1, v.shape[0]))
```

Now when you multiply `colu` and `rowv` you'll get a matrix with shape `(m, n)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a matrix - use matrices. This way you can use your expression nearly verbatim:

```
np.matrix([1,1,1,1]).T * np.matrix([2,3])
```

Comment: Thanks very much, That is exact expression I want

Comment: Actually matrices [are not recommended](https://saturncloud.io/blog/deprecation-status-of-the-numpy-matrix-class-what-data-scientists-need-to-know/), just use arrays in place. `np.matrix` will be deprecated after version 1.25.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `numpy.kron(a,b)` it takes the Kronecker product of two arrays. You can see the b vector as a block. The function puts this block, multiplied by the corresponding coefficient of the a vector, on the position of that coefficient. You can also use it for matrices.
For your example it would look like:

```
import numpy as np

vecA = np.array([[1],[1],[1],[1]])
vecB = np.array([2,3])

Out = np.kron(vecA,vecB)
```

this returns

```
>>> Out
array([[2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 3]])
```

Hope this helps you.